# How to serialize object with Dictionary to XML with C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this object AMForm with dictionary as one of its property.

```
public class AMForm
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> FormValues { get; set; }
}
```

`XmlSerializer` seems unable to serialize the dictionary property.

Comment: Do you want to serialize it to JSON or XML? Have you managed to serialize other types of objects than *Dictionary* or are you stuck on serialization in general? Errors/issues?

Comment: There's plenty of threads here with that question already. Anyway, possibly you can find your answer here: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961

Comment: I having this exception : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: I have change the property public Dictionary<string, string> FormValues { get; set; } to
    public SerializableDictionary<string, string> FormValues { get; set; }
Thanks!